# Flipping bits from 0 to 1

Tags: python

I have a bit string represented by

```
011
```

and I want to flip the bit at index zero to 1 which would give me:

```
111
```

Because python doesn't allow me to represent the bit using integer where initially i planned:

```
mybit = 011
```

which gives me an error for some error. So the only way i found was to use string to represent it:

```
mybit = "011"
```

but since string is immutable, i couldn't figure out any ways to flip the 0 at index 0 to 1. Creating a new string from scratch does not seem feasible as it doesn't look like I'm flipping it. Would appreciate some help on this

Comment: In old versions of Python, numbers that start with a leading zero were interpreted in octal rather than decimal. (This is what C has done forever, and Python did it because C did.) Since Python 2.6 you can use `0o` instead to indicate an octal literal, and since Python 3.0, a leading zero is a syntax error. (As PEP 20 says: "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.")

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track. Represent it as an integer.

```
mybit = 0b011
```

Flip bits using `^` (bitwise xor) operator. Bits that are 1 in the second operand will be flipped.

```
mybit ^= 0b100
```

Set bits (even if already set) using `|` (bitwise or). Bits that are 1 in the second operand will be set.

```
mybit |= 0b100
```

Clear bits (even if already clear) using `&` (bitwise and). Bits that are 0 in the second operand will be cleared.

```
mybit &= 0b011
```

Print in binary format.

```
print(bin(mybit))
```

Comment: Of course, this yields an `int` object which is just as immutable as `str`, so I don't know whether this will help the OP at all. (On the other hand, it's not clear whether the immutability of `str` was actually a problem either.)

Comment: I am pretty sure OP was trying to do `mybit[0] = "1"` or something similar with the string. Although `int`s are immutable, they behave enough like integers in other languages that I think this is the best solution in most cases.